# Browsers are ignoring the no-cache

Tags: html, nginx, caching

I have a SPA with vue3+vite

I want the index.html page to always be loaded from server and no browser caching ( for obvious reasons of course)

I have these in the nginx config
`add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";`

and these in the html file itself

```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

BUT my file still being cached!!!
I have tested with chrome Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) and firefox 103.0.1 (64-bit)

And Edge seems to be ignoring all cache all together and reloading everything :))

[image]

Comment: Please expand on "BUT my file still being cached!!!". Do you mean that the file is being served with your new headers and cached anyway, or do you mean that the browser is still serving an older, cached version of this file from a time before you added `no-cache`?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry I can see the `no-cache` header in the network tab but the request status code is 304

Comment: That is expected behavior with `no-cache`, which is what the header says. That wouldn't happen with `no-store`, so the question is why your nginx configuration says one thing but the header says something else. That said, `no-cache` is much better than `no-store` for an SPA. Also. those `meta` tags are nonstandard and will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
          add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
          add_header X-Cache-Status REVALIDATED;
```

my nginx config for spa

```
        location / {
            # This is due to nginx and the try_files behavior below, it will always
            # try to hit the index as part of try_files.  If I set index as something
            # that doesn't resolve, we don't have to worry about index.html being cached.
            #
            # If frequent updates occur, it's important that index.html not be cached
            # in the browser.  Otherwise the software update will only occur when the
            # cached page expires.  The If-Modified-Since is a better way to handle this
            # for SPAs with frequent updates.
            index unresolvable-file-html.html;
            try_files $uri @index;
        }
        location @index {
          add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
          add_header X-Cache-Status REVALIDATED;
          expires 0;
          try_files /index.html =404;
        }
```